# IOS - Side Loading limit issue: I can only have 2 apps instead of 3 on my physical device

Tags: ios, xcode, device, sideloading

when I side load apps on to my iphone xr, xcode has started replacing existing apps i've already side-loaded instead of just adding the additional app to the current ones I already placed on my device, is this fixable so i can have all my finished projects on my device? ..... I know about apple's new changes where a free dev account will only let you place 3 apps on a physical device per week but for some reason i can only have 2.

Comment: Apps are identified by their bundle id. If you install a build with the same bundle id as an app that is already present, it will be replaced.

Comment: thanks a million i hope many blessings find you